# CSRF protection when implementing Google custom search for a website

Tags: php, csrf, google-custom-search

Do we need to implement CSRF protection for html forms that use google custom search? I think it is not necessary. In case if we need it how should we go about it?

Comment: this is due to acunetix vulnerability scanner always report forms which use google custom search are vulnerable to CSRF attacks. I see no point in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its not required but incase you want to implement or need to have an idea, here is what I would do.

1. Create a session variable and pass the value to UI in your form.
2. Let this value be hidden in your form.
3. When user posts the form, it reaches the server. The hidden value is then compared with the session variable. If it matches, do a curl request to google server and get the response.

I suggested curl request because, if you are doing it through javascript, there is not point in keeping the CSRF validation.

Comment: I also thought about something similar. In fact this looks like the only way to do it. So we can't have the GET method in the query form isn't it? First we get the form to submit to our script via POST and from there we make the request to google as a GET request.

Comment: You can use get in the form. Its just that you need to do appropriate validation in the php script. So first you submit the form and then validate the request and then either use post or get to Google using curl. Curl is a nice way of fetching these kind of data.